# How do I navigate a website through software?

Tags: java, javascript, python, html, navigation

I need to navigate though a website that is written mostly in Javascript. There are no hard links at all, as the page is simply modified through the script. I can do what I need to using Javascript injections one after another, but chrome starts searching for my input instead of injecting it after a certain string length. I've tried to use frames to do this in HTML, but chrome won't let me use Javascript inside the frame since the source is from a different domain. Is there a good way that I can do this? I've looked into using Java or Python, but I don't see anything that lets you work with Javascript.

EDIT: Thanks for telling me about different software, but I don't want to use other third-party software. I would really like to know how to execute Javascript injections in a systematic manner from a HTML page. I can do it from the browser, so why can't I do it from an HTML document?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tool like Selenium to emulate a user clicking things in a web browser (I believe it actually "drives" a real instance of whatever browser you choose.)

Selenium has a domain-specific language for specifying what actions you want to perform, and Python bindings for controlling it programmatically. I haven't actually used it, so I can't say much more about it, but you should go check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Phantom JS](http://www.phantomjs.org/) is what you are looking for? It's a Headless Webkit with a JavaScript API - no browser required. Haven't used it yet, but our company is looking at it for JavaScript Unit testing automation.